# Computing values in between Angular UI binding

Tags: angularjs

Angular two ways UI binding is great. It is so easy to use because angular handle binding the value automatically. but what if I want to compute the value in between bindings, something like getter and setters to computed the value. How shall I go about it?

I see that we can use `filters` for getters, but what about setters?? what I want is when a user inputs a number like 10, I need to compute it before setting to the scope model. any ideas?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the unprocessed value to the scope, watch it and compute the derived value:

```
$scope.userInput = 3;

$scope.watch('userInput', function(newValue) {
   $scope.computedUserInput = newValue + 1;
});
```

Alternatively, if you are using a default directive that supports ng-change, you could simply use that and call a method in your scope directly.

And a third way would be using ngModelController which I find a bit heavy for some simple cases but provides the transparency you seem to be seeking: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I think the two approaches your propose above both break the two-way data bindings. isn't that?

Comment: In a way, yes. To my knowledge, there is no way to preprocess user input using the simple two way binding notation.

Comment: You could always define getters/setters on your scope if you only support > IE8; But I usually stay clear of these in application code.

Comment: I think the third option is the right way to do it. thanks for helping finding the solution. much appreciated.